# Enviar email con ajax html php

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buen Dia, Programqadores mi `problemas es con enviar email con ajax html php No consigo enviar el email de mi pagina web en el ajax pasa muy bien las informaciones y validaciones dice enviar el mensaje pero no es asi
me valida todo y dice enviar el email pero no llega ningun email al correo que puse para que reciba el email y ya nose que poner por que  me pide mas caracteres para publicar esa pregunta si podrian ser tan amables de sacarme de la duda de en que parte esta mal mi codigo

**mi html**

```
          <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-n2">
            <div class="form-group select">
              <label for="inputState">Motivo del Contacto</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="motive" required="required">
                <option value="Deseo hacer una donación" selected>Deseo hacer una donación</option>
                <option value="Deseo solicitar una donación">Deseo solicitar una donación</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre" required="required"
                data-validation-required-message="Por Favor Ingrese su Nombre" />
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Tu Email*" required="required"
                data-validation-required-message="Por Favor ingrese su Email" />
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Tu Numero de Celular/telefono *"
                required="required"
                data-validation-required-message="Por Favor Ingrese un Numero de Celular/Telefono" />
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-n2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Tu Mensaje*" required="required"
                data-validation-required-message="Por Favor ingrese un Mensaje"></textarea>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-uppercase" type="submit">
              Enviar
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**mi ajax**

```
    $(function () {
  $(
    "#contactForm input,#contactForm select,#contactForm textarea"
  ).jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
      // mensajes de error adicionales o eventos
    },
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // evitar el comportamiento de envío predeterminado
      //get valores de FORM
      var motive = $("select#motive").val();
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // Mensaje de éxito / fracaso

      //  Verifique el espacio en blanco en el nombre del mensaje de éxito / falla
      if (firstName.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
      }

      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Deshabilita el botón de envío hasta que la llamada AJAX se complete para evitar mensajes duplicados
      $.ajax({
        url: "../mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: name,
          motive: motive,
          email: email,
          phone: phone,
          message: message,
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
          //   Mensaje de éxito
          $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $("#success > .alert-success")
            .html(
              "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
            )
            .append("</button>");
          $("#success > .alert-success").append(
            "<strong> Tu mensaje ha sido enviado.</strong>"
          );
          $("#success > .alert-success").append("</div>");
          // borrar todos los campos
          $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function () {
          //Mensaje Error
          $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $("#success > .alert-danger")
            .html(
              "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
            )
            .append("</button>");
          $("#success > .alert-danger").append(
            $("<strong>").text(
              "Disculpa " +
                firstName +
                ", ocurrio un error al Enviar el Email. Por Favor intente mas Tarde!"
            )
          );
          $("#success > .alert-danger").append("</div>");
          // borrar todos los campos
          $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); //  Vuelve a habilitar el botón de envío cuando se complete la llamada AJAX
          }, 1000);
        },
      });
    },
    filter: function () {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});
```

**mi php**

```
 <?php
// Verificar campos vacíos

if (
   empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['motive'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])
) {
   echo "No hay argumentos proporcionados!";
   return false;
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$motive = $_POST['motive'];
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));


// Crea el correo electrónico y envía el mensaje
$to = 'asanchez@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Formulario de contacto del sitio web:  $name";

$email_body =  "Recibió un nuevo mensaje del formulario de contacto de su sitio web.\n\n"
               ."El Motivo de Contacto $motive \n\n".
               "Aquí están los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTelefon: $phone\n\nMensaje:\n$message";
$headers .= "Responder a : $email_address";

//Enviar el Correo
mail($to,$email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

return true;

?>
```

Comment: Haz una prueba: retorná un json desde el php al ajax para chequear que todos los datos lleguen correctamente y hacele console.log.

Comment: Puede ser que tengas que configurar el servidor SMTP para enviar el correo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo estoy viendo estas usando la vieja funcion de php para enviar email directamente, es decir, sin el servicio SMTP, por lo tanto para que esta funcion te sirva debes enviar los mensajes desde un servidor, tu pagina web directamente, ya que si lo haces desde localhost no va a funcionar, ahora si vas a usar el servicio smtp simplemente descarga las librerias y a tu codigo de php añadele esa libreria quedando por ejemplo asi

```
include 'smtp/Send_Mail.php';
$to = 'asanchez@gmail.com'; etc..
```

en el archivo Send_mail.php tengo lo importantes que es:

```
$from       = "correo@tudominio.com";
$mail       = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true);            // use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "tls://host.tudominio.com"; // Este dato lo puedes sacar desde el cpanel con el servicio de emails
$mail->Port       =  465;                    // Este dato lo puedes sacar desde el cpanel con el servicio de emails
$mail->Username   = "correo@tudominio.com";  // Este dato lo puedes sacar desde el cpanel con el servicio de emails
$mail->Password   = "clavedelcorrreo";  // Este dato lo puedes sacar desde el cpanel con el servicio de emails
$mail->SetFrom($from, 'Tu dominio');
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,'Tu dominio');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $to;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);
$mail->Send();
```

Como veras estoy definiendo el servicio de correos desde donde se va a conectar para enviar los emails, ahora ¿qué estoy solicitando acá para enviar el correo?

Pues simple, $to, $subject y $body y para realizar el envio de ese correo se añade:

```
Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
```

Ahora como quedaria tu codigo php adaptandolo a ese sistema seria:

```
include 'smtp/Send_Mail.php';
$to = 'asanchez@gmail.com'; 
$subject = "Formulario de contacto del sitio web:  $name";

$body =  "Recibió un nuevo mensaje del formulario de contacto de su sitio web.\n\n"
               ."El Motivo de Contacto $motive \n\n".
               "Aquí están los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTelefon: $phone\n\nMensaje:\n$message
\nResponder a : $email_address
";

//Enviar el Correo
Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
```

No soy muy bueno en esto, solo te comparto mi experiencia de lo que ya he hecho y me ha funcionado.

Si no tienes un servidor web, puedes usar el servicio que ofrece gmail simplemente tendrias que permitir a tu cuenta gmail la entrada a aplicaciones pocos seguras [Haz click aqui](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps?pli=1)

Luego al archivo Send_mail modifica lo siguiente

```
$mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port       =  465;                  
$mail->Username   = "tu_usuario@gmail.com";  //Aqui colocas el usuario de gmail con que accedes a la cuenta
$mail->Password   = "clave de tu cuenta gmail";
```

Y listo ya puedes enviar tu correo